# Show Duplicates on MySQL bulk insert

Tags: mysql, duplicates, bulkinsert

I have a CSV file which I need to enter into my Database. My modus operandi is a Bulk insert. One of the columns has a uniqueness constraint attached to it but it is not the primary column. If there is a duplicate entry, it correctly skips the line and does not enter it into the database. (On command line it indicates Duplicates: n, where n is  the total number of duplicates).

Is there anyway I can retrieve the duplicate row numbers ? For instance, using Show Warnings or Show Errors, it states the last MySQL errors and warnings, is there anyway I can retrieve the duplicates from MySQL alone ?

Thanks.

Comment: What are you using to do the bulk insert?

Comment: Eh ? Insert ignore into tablename(columname1,columname2..) values(val1,val2,..), (val1,val2,...), (val1,val2,...);

Comment: Never mind, I misread the question. You want more detailed information, not just the count of duplicates. I don't think that's available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could enter the data into a temporary table first, without the uniqueness constraint, and perform a query to find all the duplicates.

```
SELECT unique_column, count(*) c
FROM temp_tablename
GROUP BY unique_column
HAVING c > 1;
```

Then copy it from the temporary table to the real table with:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO tablename SELECT * FROM temp_tablename;
```